# mongodb morphia save with id not override

Tags: mongodb, morphia

mongo morphia basicDAO.save() basicly does

```
save(T entity)
Saves the entity; either inserting or overriding the existing document
```

If entity.id is NOT null, morphia will try to override existing document, is there a way to let morphia throws an duplicate key Exception (like mongodb does) instead?

Comment: Just curious - what is your @Id field? Why not use ObjectId and you're pretty much guaranteed to not have conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach is for you to check if the document already exists. The most performant is to use:

```
db.collection.find({_id: “myId”}, {_id: 1}).limit(1)
```

And then check for null or not. 'findOne' will actually load the document from the database so avoid that.